# Sqlite Scrolling Cursor How to Scroll Correctly with duplicate names

Tags: sql, sqlite, scroll, cursor

I have implemented a scrolling cursor with SQL Lite and C#.
Well the I am only testing with SQL in an SQL Lite tool.

So I have it functioning the scrolling cursor from:

http://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor

So I have this working but the results are not correct.

```
SELECT title FROM tracks
     WHERE singer='Madonna'
       AND title>:lasttitle
     ORDER BY title
     LIMIT 5;
```

So say these are the fields in my track table:

track_id
singer
title
media_format

and say I have a bunch of records ()

```
4    Madonna    <All my love demo>    .mp3
2    Madonna    <Be cool demo>    .wav
7    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .aaf
1    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .adi
5    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .mp4
11    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .wmv
3    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .mp5
8    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .mp6
10   Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .mp7
9    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .mp8
6   Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .mp9
```

So basically I have unlimited records of the same title as long as the media_format is different, the media_format makes them unique.

The records are ordered by title (as you can see in the query) so the unique id is not in order.

How can I do the scrolling cursor, when scrolling forward to get the next 5 records where the lastitle was

**lets say I have already loading the first page into my C# app and I then I scroll forward with  in the lastitle variable**

It will not give me the correct records.
so if I change the greater than > to greater than or equal to >= then it will give me 5 records starting with the first occurrence of  but I need it to start on record 6

I need to see:

page 1

```
4    Madonna    <All my love demo>    .mp3
2    Madonna    <Be cool demo>    .wav
7    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .aaf
1    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .adi
5    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .mp4
```

page 2

```
11    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .wmv
3    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .mp5
8    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .mp6
10   Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .mp7
9    Madonna    <Like a Virgin>    .mp8
```

Comment: use  `title+media_format>:lasttitle`. Obviously you will have to store title+media_format in the lasttitle variable in your C# code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your records must be completely ordered.

If the columns in your WHERE filter (here: `singer`/`title`) could identify multiple records, you must add other columns to make the filter unique.
This could be the `media_format` in your case, but if your program doesn't know what other column could be used, it should just use the primary key (`track_id` or the `rowid`).

If you sort by multiple columns, the WHERE expression becomes more complex.
Take, for example, the following table, sorted by `X` and `Y`:

```
X Y
- -
A 1
A 2  <- last record on previous page
A 3
B 1
B 2
```

To get all records after the previous record, you have to search for records with the same `X` value and larger `Y` values, or with larger `X` values:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (X = 'A' AND Y > 2)
   OR (X > 'A')
ORDER BY X, Y
```

In your example, this would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM tracks
WHERE singer = 'Madonna'
  AND ((title = :lasttitle AND media_format > :lastformat) OR
        title > :lasttitle)
ORDER BY title, media_format
LIMIT ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The new row value feature in SQLite 3.15 can assist in making the query syntax more legible (see https://sqlite.org/rowvalue.html).  You still need to ensure your ORDER BY provides a unique result per row, and you will need to have appropriate indexes created for fast results.

You initial query appears much the same:

```
SELECT * FROM tracks
WHERE singer = 'Madonna' 
ORDER BY title,media_format,track_id
LIMIT 5;
```

Store title,media_format,track_id of the last result row.  Then provide it for your next query (here as ?1,?2,?3):

```
SELECT * FROM tracks
WHERE singer = 'Madonna' 
AND (title,media_format,track_id) > (?1,?2,?3)
ORDER BY title,media_format,track_id
LIMIT 5;
```

That results in an easier to read query.